# Defining an AUC metric for Keras to support evaluation of validation dataset

Tags: keras

I am trying to implement an AUC metric for Keras so that I have AUC measurement after my validation set runs during a `model.fit()` run.

I define the metric as such:

```
def auc(y_true, y_pred):   
    keras.backend.get_session().run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    keras.backend.get_session().run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    keras.backend.get_session().run(tf.initialize_local_variables())

    #return K.variable(value=tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_auc(
    #    y_pred, y_true)[0], dtype='float32')
    return tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_auc(y_pred, y_true)[0]
```

This results in the following error which I don't know understand.

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: 
Attempting to use uninitialized value auc/true_positives...
```

From online reading, it seems that the problem is 2-fold, a bug in tensorflow/keras and partially and issue with tensorflow being unable to initialize local variables from inference.  Given these 2 issues, I do not see why I get this error or how to overcome it.  Any suggestions?

I wrote two other metrics that work just fine:

```
# PFA, prob false alert for binary classifier
def binary_PFA(y_true, y_pred, threshold=K.variable(value=0.5)):
    y_pred = K.cast(y_pred >= threshold, 'float32')
    # N = total number of negative labels
    N = K.sum(1 - y_true)
    # FP = total number of false alerts, alerts from the negative class labels
    FP = K.sum(y_pred - y_pred * y_true)    
    return FP/N

# P_TA prob true alerts for binary classifier
def binary_PTA(y_true, y_pred, threshold=K.variable(value=0.5)):
    y_pred = K.cast(y_pred >= threshold, 'float32')
    # P = total number of positive labels
    P = K.sum(y_true)
    # TP = total number of correct alerts, alerts from the positive class labels
    TP = K.sum(y_pred * y_true)    
    return TP/P
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run tf.initialize_local_variables() before you return the auc tensor

```
def auc(y_true, y_pred):
     auc = tf.metrics.auc(y_true, y_pred)[1]
     K.get_session().run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
     return auc
```

This initializes the TP, FP, TN, FN to zeros. Note that this would give the correct auc score only the first time it's computed since the  TP, FP, TN, FN variables have to be initalized to zeros after each run.

Answer (score 7):

Here are the tricks that I often use. Basically, this allows you to use whatever existing metrics in `sklearn`

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
import tensorflow as tf
def auc( y_true, y_pred ) :
    score = tf.py_func( lambda y_true, y_pred : roc_auc_score( y_true, y_pred, average='macro', sample_weight=None).astype('float32'),
                        [y_true, y_pred],
                        'float32',
                        stateful=False,
                        name='sklearnAUC' )
    return score
```

Now we can create a simple model to verify this metric.

```
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model

x = Input(shape=(100,))
y = Dense(10, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
model.compile( 'sgd', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[auc] )
print model.summary()


a = np.random.randn(1000,100)
b = np.random.randint(low=0,high=2,size=(1000,10))
model.fit( a, b )
```

Comment: +1 & the most simple solution from a copy-and-paste point of view. However the code is a bit messy and a bit more explanation around what's going on would make this excellent :)

Comment: This code raises an error:


TypeError: eager_py_func() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stateful'